# Error on prepared statements SQL syntax

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, prepared-statement

The queria above works in MySqlWorkBench

```
select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4 from test_table t1,
(select count(col2) n, col2 from test_table group by col2) t2
where t2.n > 1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2;`
```

But when i use in my Java method .. with PreparedStatement stmt i get error 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server"

this is my method:

```
public ArrayList<Tuple> getRepeatedTuples(String columns) {

    ArrayList<Tuple> tuples = new ArrayList<Tuple>();

    String sql = "select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4"
            + "from test_table t1, (select count(?) n, ? from test_table group by ? ) t2 where t2.n > 1 AND t1.? = t2.?";

    try {
        // prepared statement para inserção
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, columns);
        stmt.setString(2, columns);
        stmt.setString(3, columns);
        stmt.setString(4, columns);
        stmt.setString(5, columns);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            // criando o objeto Tuple

            Tuple tuple = new Tuple();
            tuple.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            tuple.setValue1(rs.getString("col1"));
            tuple.setValue2(rs.getString("col2"));
            tuple.setValue3(rs.getString("col3"));
            tuple.setValue4(rs.getLong("col4"));

            tuples.add(tuple);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return tuples;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

need help constructing the preparedStatement. 
Thanks

Comment: try select count(*) n, col2 from test_table group by col2

Comment: `"..col4" + "from.."` - you are missing a space before the `FROM`. It usually helps to print out the generated statement and try to run **exactly** that.

Comment: thanks for help guys … I made a print … and query returned is

select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4 from test_table t1, (select count(*) n, 'col2' from test_table group by 'col2' ) t2 where t2.n > 1 AND t1.'col2' = t2.'col2'
so there line which is giving error 'col2' and t1.'col2' = t2.'col2' the DataBase take as string and not as table.. any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: this part is fixed thank you.. Beyond missing space  the value were passed inside comma  'value ' my  mysql was getting as string not as column name . I made toString.replace(" ' ", "") ;

I got new error in this part of querie .  SELECT t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2…